# How can I solve mismatch input size in caffe visualization?

Tags: python, caffe

I have trained my network with AlexNet model and I have the model weights. Now I want to test it on my test data. here is part of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
net = caffe.Net(model_def,      # defines the structure of the model
            model_weights,  # contains the trained weights
            caffe.TEST)
print 'net.blobs['data'].data.shape = ', net.blobs['data'].data.shape

# create transformer for the input called 'data'
transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})

transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))  # move image channels to outermost dimension
#transformer.set_mean('data', mu)            # subtract the dataset-mean value in each channel
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255)      # rescale from [0, 1] to [0, 255]
#transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2,1,0))  # swap channels from RGB to BGR

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
# set the size of the input 
#net.blobs['data'].reshape(1,        # batch size
#                          1,        # 3-channel (BGR) images
#                       227, 227,  # image size is 227x227


image = cv2.imread('p225232.jpg')
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print 'original image: ', np.shape(image)
print 'convert to gray image: ', np.shape(image1)

image = caffe.io.load_image('p225232.jpg')
transformed_image = transformer.preprocess('data', image1)
print np.shape(image)
print np.shape(transformed_image)

# show net information
for layer_name, blob in net.blobs.iteritems():
    print layer_name + '\t' + str(blob.data.shape)
```

and the output for this run is:

```
net.blobs['data'].data.shape = (1, 1, 227, 227)
original image:  (228, 228, 3)
convert to gray image:  (228, 228)
caffe.io.load_image('p225232.jpg') = (228, 228, 3)
transformed_image size = (3, 227, 227)

data    (1, 227, 227)
conv1   (1, 96, 55, 55)
norm1   (1, 96, 55, 55)
pool1   (1, 96, 27, 27)
conv2   (1, 256, 27, 27)
norm2   (1, 256, 27, 27)
pool2   (1, 256, 13, 13)
conv3   (1, 384, 13, 13)
conv4   (1, 384, 13, 13)
conv5   (1, 256, 13, 13)
pool5   (1, 256, 6, 6)
fc6 (1, 4096)
fc7 (1, 4096)
fc8 (1, 4)
prob    (1, 4)
conv1   (96, 1, 11, 11) (96,)
conv2   (256, 48, 5, 5) (256,)
conv3   (384, 256, 3, 3) (384,)
conv4   (384, 192, 3, 3) (384,)
conv5   (256, 192, 3, 3) (256,)
fc6 (4096, 9216) (4096,)
fc7 (4096, 4096) (4096,)
fc8 (4, 4096) (4,)
```

but then when I run:

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformed_image
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,227,227) into shape (1,227,227)
```

I am very much confused with that creating transformer for the input part!
1- first of all i do not have that `.npy` file! how can I get it?
2- second if i do not do that transformation why I am not able to continue?
3- how can I match these sizes from the input data to the transformed data? (solve the error I encounter)
4- it may seem an easy question but when I read my image data in MATLAB it is 288*288 but when I read the same image I get an image with size 288*288*3. why?

Could you please help me find the solutions for my question??!!

Comment: Do you have `deploy.prototxt` where the caffe prototxt network structure exists? If you have this file you can get the idea of transformation part...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to convert your image to grey scale. I do not really know how to do it with a `caffe.io.transformer` object (in fact I would say you can't). But a `np.mean` afterwards could make the work

```py
image = caffe.io.load_image('p225232.jpg')
transformed_image = transformer.preprocess('data', image1)
transformed_image = np.mean(tranformed_image, axis=0)
```